# Adding remove class section to existing eventlistener loop

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do, is loop through all my .nav__btn elements, use them as buttons through the addEventListener, and through that add the class .open to certain elements.

This part actually works fine, and I even managed to make it remove the .open class from other elements, when a new one is triggered.

However, I have tried in multiple ways now to make it remove the .open class, if the same button is pressed again.

I have tried using:

```
if (sections[x].classList.contains('open')) { 
    sections.classList.remove('open')
}
```

in different locations of the function, but without success. Either it breaks the script or simply has no effect.

my only solution is creating a completely seperate function to handle this matter, and have 2 EventListeners on the same elements, but I think it can be worked into this script. I just do not have the skills to do so, aparently.

Below a complete snippet:

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__btn');
var sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  (function(x) {
    btns[x].addEventListener('click', _ => {

      if (sections[x].classList.contains('open')) {
        sections[x].classList.remove('open')
      }

      sections.forEach(section => {
        if (section.classList.contains('open')) {
          section.classList.remove('open')
        }
      })

      sections[x].classList.toggle('open')
    })
  })(i)
}
```

```css
section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  opacity: 0;
  visiblity: 0;
  z-index: 30;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
  background: #00ff00;
}

section:nth-child(3) {
  background: #ff0000;
}

section:nth-child(4) {
  background: #0000ff;
}

section:nth-child(5) {
  background: #ccc;
}

.open {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="nav__list">
    <li><span class="nav__btn">Button 1</span></li>
    <li><span class="nav__btn">Button 2</span></li>
    <li><span class="nav__btn">Button 3</span></li>
    <li><span class="nav__btn">Button 4</span></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section>section 1</section>
<section>section 2</section>
<section>section 3</section>
<section>section 4</section>
```

Additionaly, here is a JsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/ajLxbqzk/4/

Comment: Sure.. that makes sense my bad. Give a minute or two.

Comment: What is `btns`? I suspect that your code is removing classes from elements in an array, but that doesn't update the DOM.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ajLxbqzk/3/ here is the example. I also added it to the post.

Comment: Is this better? https://jsfiddle.net/ajLxbqzk/4/

Comment: Are you  missing a [x] in  the first sections.classList.remove('open') ?

Comment: Indeed that is a typo, but it doesn't fix it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle correctly sections display, you can loop through them this way:

- If a `section` is associated to the button, **toggle** its display
- Otherwise, **hide** it

Below a working version:

```
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__btn');
var sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');

// We loop through all buttons in the btns collection
// "i" is the index of the current button processed in the loop
btns.forEach((btn, i) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', _ => {
    // If btns[i] is clicked, loop through sections...
    sections.forEach((section, j) => {
      if (i == j) {
        // The current section is of index i (because i == j)
        // We toogle it
        section.classList.toggle('open');
      } else {
        // Other sections are just hided
        section.classList.remove('open');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by i i need to fix those two lines?

Comment: As a very green coder, indeed there are some things that is not clear to me :)

I think i get most of it, with emphasis on i think - but.. what does "this" refer in this line? this.sections.forEach((section, j) => {

My guess would be the pressed button, but i am not sure.. at all.

Comment: I think i get the jist of it. running btns foreach loop, placing them in an array called "i", then adding an EventListener for clicks, that will on click event run sections through a foreach loop placing this value in a variable called "j" - then if (i = j) makes sure that button 3 gets section 3 and then toggling or removing .open class.

That is probably a bad explanation, but it's the best my rookie-coder-brain can muster right now haha

Comment: YUP! - indeed mine was a terrible explanation. :D

Thanks for the help! I will go read up and make sure that i eliminate any doubt, when i have to explain this at some point :P

Comment: I actually went to MDN before coming here, in order to attempt to solve the problem myself. But i had to admit defeat :D
I'm pretty sure it's a ME thing, and not an MDN thing ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is your click handler code:

```
  //1
  if (sections[x].classList.contains('open')) {
    sections[x].classList.remove('open')
  }

  //2
  sections.forEach(section => {
    if (section.classList.contains('open')) {
      section.classList.remove('open')
    }
  })

  //3
  sections[x].classList.toggle('open')
```

I labeled it into three steps. When you click a button, these three things happen:

1. If the current section was open, close it.
2. Close all open sections.
3. Toggle the current section.

Step 1 is redundant because step 2 closes all sections anyway - the end result will always be all sections being closed.

Since step 2 ensures that *all sections are always closed* by the time you reach step 3, step 3 only can possibly do one thing: set the current section to open. The current section can never be open at this point - because it was just closed in *both* step 1 and 2 - so `sections[x].classList.toggle('open')` can't possibly do anything other than make the section open.

What you've described as what you *want* to happen is not the function that you wrote. What you want is something like this:

1. Close all *other* sections.
2. Toggle the current section.

Because that way, when step 2 runs, the current section might still be open, therefore toggling it sets it to closed. So all you have to do is write it exactly as described:

```
  //1 - close all sections EXCEPT sections[x]
  sections.forEach(section => {
    if (section != sections[x] && section.classList.contains('open')) {
      section.classList.remove('open')
    }
  })

  //2 - toggle sections[x]
  sections[x].classList.toggle('open')
```

Here it is in your complete example:

```js
var btns = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__btn');
var sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  (function(x) {
    btns[x].addEventListener('click', _ => {

      //1 - close all sections EXCEPT sections[x]
      sections.forEach(section => {
        if (section != sections[x] && section.classList.contains('open')) {
          section.classList.remove('open')
        }
      })

      //2 - toggle sections[x]
      sections[x].classList.toggle('open')
    })
  })(i)
}
```

```css
section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  opacity: 0;
  visiblity: 0;
  z-index: 30;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
  background: #00ff00;
}

section:nth-child(3) {
  background: #ff0000;
}

section:nth-child(4) {
  background: #0000ff;
}

section:nth-child(5) {
  background: #ccc;
}

.open {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="nav__list">
    <li><span class="nav__btn">Button 1</span></li>
    <li><span class="nav__btn">Button 2</span></li>
    <li><span class="nav__btn">Button 3</span></li>
    <li><span class="nav__btn">Button 4</span></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section>section 1</section>
<section>section 2</section>
<section>section 3</section>
<section>section 4</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

I really don't like using loops in code. It creates messy code and looping over elements takes time. I prefer storing variables instead.

I removed your inner method that had `x` as an argument. Instead, I changed `var i` in your loop to `let i`, otherwise i would have the value of 4 inside the anonymous click method.

I created a content element as a container for all the sections which I which added "content" as an id.

I then just add the attribute `previous-index` to content and let that keep track of which section that was previously opened and let an if statement decide if I should remove the `open` class or not. I could use a global variable outside of the click methods but using global variables are always in the risk of being overwritten in larger projects.

I'm using `sectionIsOpen` and `newButtonClicked` in order to explain code through variables, because it's harder to read "not statements", like `i != previouslyClickedIndex`.

Finally, you're using the wrong values on `visibility`. It should be `hidden` or `visible`, not 0 or 1.

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.nav__btn');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
const content = document.getElementById('content');

for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    const NOT_SET = -1;
    let previouslyClickedIndex = content.getAttribute('previous-index') || NOT_SET;        
    let sectionIsOpen = previouslyClickedIndex != NOT_SET;
    let newButtonClicked = i != previouslyClickedIndex;
    
    if (sectionIsOpen && newButtonClicked) {
      sections[previouslyClickedIndex].classList.remove('open');
    }

    sections[i].classList.toggle('open');

    content.setAttribute('previous-index', i);
  });
}
```

```css
section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  opacity: 0;
  visiblity: hidden;
  z-index: 30;
}

section:nth-child(2) {
  background: #00ff00;
}

section:nth-child(3) {
  background: #ff0000;
}

section:nth-child(4) {
  background: #0000ff;
}

section:nth-child(5) {
  background: #ccc;
}

.open {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="nav__list">
    <li><span class="nav__btn">Button 1</span></li>
    <li><span class="nav__btn">Button 2</span></li>
    <li><span class="nav__btn">Button 3</span></li>
    <li><span class="nav__btn">Button 4</span></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<content id="content">
  <section>section 1</section>
  <section>section 2</section>
  <section>section 3</section>
  <section>section 4</section>
</content>
```

Comment: I'm on thin ice now, but in this particular case, it doesn't matter. It's good to use `data-*` to avoid the page breaking if the spec of HTML changes in the future, and it's necessary if you want to use vanilla HTML (instead of custom elements) and style elements based on your custom attributes. You can read more about attributes here: https://javascript.info/dom-attributes-and-properties